# Search a column using an input and get a row when the input matches

Tags: php, arrays

I need a little bit of help. I've googled the crap out of this and keep getting answers that aren't what I want.

Okay now lets say this is my array

```
<?php  $shop = array( array("rose", 1.25 , 15),
           array("daisy", 0.75 , 25),
           array("orchid", 1.15 , 7) 
         ); ?>
```

How can I search this array. After I find what I need I can select the row that this information was found in. After selecting the row I can choose what information in the row in which the information was found.

For example:

I want to find the price of a orchid. So I would type in orchid then it would select the row orchid was on after doing this it would move over to the second column and get 1.15. Or if I wanted to know how many orchids there were in stock it would select the third row.

Comment: get the value for the second row ??

Comment: not just the second row but any row.

Comment: can you clarify your expected output with example ?

Comment: This would probably be better as an associative array, so PHP could do the lookup for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$shop = array( array("rose", 1.25 , 15),
           array("daisy", 0.75 , 25),
           array("orchid", 1.15 , 7) 
         );

$search="daisy";         

foreach($shop as $a)
  if($a[0]==$search)
    echo $a[1];         

?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I see what you did now. Please ignore my last comment